# aspx vb.net checkboxlist to be populated from sql server

Tags: vb.net, checkboxlist

can you populate checkboxlist from sql server query like a dropdownlist? with autopostback=true? i am using vb.net and have 50 checkboxes that shall show up from the database data depending on the selected value of the previous dropdownlist. also can i change the label of the checkbox each time the value is from DB? the label shall be same as the checkbox value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CheckBoxList's `ControlId` is myCheckBoxList:

```
Dim mySQL As String = "Name_of_stored_proceedure"
Dim mySqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("The_connection_string")
Dim mySqlCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(mySQL, mySqlConnection)
mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure      
Dim myDataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
mySqlConnection.Open()
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
mySqlConnection.Close()
myCheckBoxList.DataSource = myDataTable
myCheckBoxList.DataBind()
```

This is the process to use a stored procedure. If you would like to use straight SQL or a parametrized query take out the `mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` and put the SQL in for the "Name_of_stored_proceedure".

Remember to put the column name from the database in the `DataValueField` property of the CheckBoxList that you would like to for the the value and the column name for the `DataTextField` you would like to use for the text.